# SharePoint 2013 Online Permission to User Profiles REST API

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, rest

I have a SharePoint application which I've built using javascript on a single page (not using an app). I have to make calls to the user profile service to retrieve properties like Manager and Business Area etc for whoever the current user selects in a people picker using REST. This works fine when I'm the current user as I'm a 365 global admin, but other users get access denied on the REST call. Presumably they don't have permission to read user profile properties for other users with REST. How would I get round this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to elevate the app permissions.
User Profile Service use tenant/farm level permissions.

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```